# Logstash replace all json keys on filter

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-filter

My logstash receives JSONs with some key name that contains '.' . I want to replace all dots with other string in all key names.

I found kv,json,mutate but it seems that there is no plugin that can iterate over every JSON key.

Is there any other plugin that could help beside writing code in Ruby plugin?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your json so people can see how your data looks like? Also share what is your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

After a scan of the documentation, the only option I see for you is the [gsub filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub). Code copied from the docs

```
filter {
      mutate {
        gsub => [
          # replace all forward slashes with underscore
          "fieldname", "/", "_",
          # replace backslashes, question marks, hashes, and minuses
          # with a dot "."
          "fieldname2", "[\\?#-]", "."
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: But is it possible to iterate over all of the fields even if I dont't know the names of the fields? In your example you must provide the field names, I want something like 'for each'

Comment: Not as far as the documentation goes. I am afraid your only choice appears to be using ruby code :-\